# Bypass unresolvable error when cleaning packages with package manager?

Tags: homebrew, macports

Using MacPorts, when I run

```
sudo port -f clean --all all
```

Then I get an error. Snippet of output below:

```
--->  Cleaning ml
--->  Cleaning mldonkey
--->  Cleaning mlpack
--->  Cleaning mlt
Error: Unable to open port: Package Qt5Core was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Qt5Core.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

I don't know which one is causing the problem (I tried uninstalling/installing `mlt` but that doesn't do it). This may not be specific to MacPorts, but [I see the same error with homebrew posted](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5955) so maybe it is more general.

I searched in /opt/local/ which is the installation directory of MacPorts but I don't have Qt5Core.pc.

Is there a way to make this MacPorts command continue running (kind of like with exception handling) and continue cleaning other packages after the error is encountered?

Answer (score 1):

The error has been reported at https://trac.macports.org/ticket/54861. A workaround patch has been provided.

> ```
> diff --git a/multimedia/mlt/Portfile b/multimedia/mlt/Portfile
> --- a/multimedia/mlt/Portfile
> +++ b/multimedia/mlt/Portfile
> @@ -42,7 +42,7 @@ if {${subport} eq "${name}"} {
>      if {[info procs qt5.active_version] eq ""} {
>          proc qt5.active_version {} {
>              global prefix
> -            if {[file exists ${prefix}/bin/pkg-config]} {
> +            if {[file exists ${prefix}/bin/pkg-config/Qt5Core.pc]} {
>                  set av [exec ${prefix}/bin/pkg-config --modversion Qt5Core]
>                  return ${av}
>              } else {
> @@ -53,10 +53,15 @@ if {${subport} eq "${name}"} {
>
>      qt5.depends_component \
>                      qtsvg
> -    if {[vercmp [qt5.active_version] 5.7.0] >= 0} {
> -        configure.cxxflags-append \
> -                    -stdlib=libc++ \
> -                    -std=c++11
> +    pre-configure {
> +        # qt5.active_version only works if Qt is installed; we can
> +        # be certain that is the case in the pre-configure phase.
> +        if {[vercmp [qt5.active_version] 5.7.0] >= 0} {
> +            ui_debug "Qt 5.7.0 and up require at least C++11"
> +            configure.cxxflags-append \
> +                        -stdlib=libc++ \
> +                        -std=c++11
> +        }
>      }
>  }
> ```